# PHPExcel deletion is not removing all the data in a coloumn

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am trying to delete all the coloumns which do not have a value curresponding to its head using phpexcel.

I dont have a value for the coloumn `AR` and `AT` to `AZ`. As shown in the figure.

[image: Delete Column Issue]

In case you cant see the image try the URL : https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/15168579/24894577/e43f7df4-1ea8-11e7-9a8d-b2c5b021202d.jpg

So i  deleted those coloumns using `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->removeColumn($i, $n);` and all the coloumns are deleted perfectly. But the problem is occured when deleting `AR`. After deleting the coloumn `AR` the coloumn `AS` is shifted to `AR` But the value in the `AS` is not deleted?

Is there any idea to remove this previous data in the previous cell ?

**EDIT :**
As Mark suggested i have reported it as an issue in Github - [Github Link](http://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/issues/1181)

Comment: If it isn't doing what it's supposed to do, then report it as a bug

Comment: I thought there will some other way to delete the coloumn thats why i posted a question here. If there is no answer i will report it as a bug.

Comment: As I wrote the code, and know that the only way to delete a column is to call the `removeColumn()` method, then I'd suggest recommending it as a bug.... I didn't provide any alternative methods that do work correctly

Comment: Reported as an issue in Github https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/issues/1181